# How does signing up / logging in with social media accounts alter user behaviour?

Tags: login, social-media, signup-signon

Assuming logging in with Facebook/Google etc. gives the social media company access to and ability to record all the interactions of the user on your website, how does this affect the behaviour of the user on your website?

Comment: This is not a UX question. Could you rephrase it? As it is it may be better suited in another SE site.

Comment: My question is: should the user singing up with social login expect the social media company to access and record all your information you enter on your site? (But yes maybe I should be asking on a different SE site.) This alters the user experience of the website, if the site is considered separate, or an extension of the social network.

Comment: My understanding is YES. You should take that for granted. Nonetheless the question is not UX related. You could rephrase it by asking how users might alter their behavior as a result of Facebook tracking their actions.

Comment: Do you know which SE site I should ask it on? I'll then delete this one, or edit it to the behaviour approach as you suggested.

Comment: I think, re-worded, it would be an excellent question. As far as where? I would ask at stackoverflow - but perhaps others could recommend another site

Comment: Thanks a lot Mayo. I'll alter this question, then ask over there.

Comment: What do you mean by alter user behavior? Because I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I would answer, however, I'm signed in, so I won't :-)

Comment: @Majo0od - Some people (and I'm one of them) refuse to use Facebook as their authentication on 3rd party sites (example commenting on an article). This alters their behavior.

Comment: I see, so that's what you mean. I too have the same feeling @mayo, I was looking for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Personally it depends on WHO is using this social media authentication to log me in. If it is a big well known site like StackExchange I'll log in using my facebook/google account without worry. However, if it's some random app on the app store or "sketchy" looking site I'll be much more hesitant as I won't trust them not to post for me or access any information.

Answer (score 1):

I have surprisingly noticed the following behavior with my social logins.

You may or may not use this to your advantage if you have multiple logins on your website which users need to select from.

If I happen to be on a Fun website which is about connecting with people/ friends/ family/ etc, I generally would sign in with **Facebook**.

If it's something related to professional work, career, courses, etc, I would sign in with **LinkedIn** or **G+**.

If it is a sketchy website which I do not trust, and is only for a one time visit, I would sign in with my **Email** (Secondary).

You may calculate your user's interest or loyalty to your website with these in mind, according to the category your website falls in.

So, to answer your question, the behavior of the user is altered, not as per the social network he chooses but the website he chooses the particular social network for.

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to consider this as a valid question in a grander concept of user experience. Naturally users are affected by which site log ins are accepted / offered. **What follows is strictly my personal opinion, no data to back this**.

There was a time when Facebook ubiquitous everywhere. Since then there is a strong perception of Facebook with leisure and social activities. May it be candy crush or Farmville, a Facebook authentication has become analogous to something which probably has to do with leisure and something where your friends / social interactions matter.

Google came very late in the game, but since then, they have carved up a nice niche of sites which offer Google log in. Initially it appeared that Google is playing catch up game with Facebook in the hope to bag more and more sites with their authentication. However things took a different turn when sites like [Asana](https://asana.com/), started offering only Google sign in. Asana is a productivity app, with an air of enterprise task management. Google's enterprise suite capital worked in their favor and somehow Asana and Google log in was a snug fit. I don't recall, but I have seen few more sites using only Google authentication, especially those which are interested in just identity and not the social angle.

So you have Facebook sign in with inclination towards social and leisure, and you have Google with a tinge of enterprise / business orientation. There are likes of Twitter, but I don't really know where I would place them.

So to answer your question, it should matter to you which site log ins you are offering and for what reason. People may infer the tone of your site based on that. It might not be a make or break decision for the user, but she would probably consider it.

Comment: Indeed.  It depends how much you 'trust' the social network with your data.